# Find occurrences of certain value in vector conditionally by the length of the occurrence & subset them to the list [R]

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a following dummy vector:

```
dummy_vector <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I would like to do the following:

1. find the occurences of 1's if they are appearing more than 3 times in a row
2. cut the part of the vector which would be flanking this ocurrence of 1's by 10 positions (values) to the left and 10 positions to the right from the center of this string of 1's - the resulting fragment should have fixed length of 20, containing 1's in the middle.
3. If the ones would be at the beginning of the vector, the function should add NA's to the left side of the string.
4. append the resulting vector fragments to a list.

And here is my desired output:

```
first <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
second <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)


desired_output <- list(first, second)
```

First part I can do using filtering with rle() but I can't do the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numerics:

```
a <- rle(dummy_vector)
condition <- a$lengths > 3 & a$values
b <- cumsum(c(1, head(a$lengths,-1)))[condition]
len <- a$lengths[condition]
start <-  b +  floor(len/2) - 10
end <- start + 19
Map(\(i, j)c(rep(NA, 20-length(x <- dummy_vector[i:j])),x),
    pmax(start, 1), pmin(end, length(dummy_vector)))

[[1]]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain what happens within Map function? And if there would be a situation in which those ones would be at the end of the vector?

Comment: @Euglenagracilis in the Map, extract i:j from the dummy_vector, If its less than 20, then pad NA in front. Now this does not take a case where the 1's would be at the end of the vector. Probably would need to incoorporate that in your function

Comment: Thanks, but this syntax is still unclear to me (sorry). Still trying to understand what's happening here though. Why there is no comma before catenation function? So if I would not like to append extra NA's, shall I have it done that way:
Map(\(i, j)c(dummy_vector[i:j]), pmax(start, 1), pmin(end, length(dummy_vector)))?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
a <- paste0(dummy_vector, collapse = "") #create a string
b <- gregexpr("1{4,}", a)[[1]]           #obtain the positions with 4+ 1's
len <- attr(b, 'match.length')           #Obtain the current length
start <- b +  floor(len/2) - 10          #extraction starting position
d <- sprintf("%20s", substring(a, start,  start + 19)) #Extract 20
lapply(strsplit(d, ''), as.numeric)     #Make numeric

[[1]]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
fn <- function(x) {
  res <- list()
  y <- rle(x == 1)
  key <- which(y$lengths>3 & y$values)
  z <- y$lengths
  for (i in key){
    a = ceiling((20 - z[i])/2)
    b = z[i]
    c = floor((20-z[i])/2)
    if (i == 1){
      res[[match(i,key)]] <- c(rep(NA, a), rep(1, b), rep(0, c))
    } else {
      res[[match(i,key)]] <- c(rep(0, a), rep(1, b), rep(0, c))
    }
  }
  return(res)
}

fn(dummy_vector)
```

Comment: Thanks. And what if the ones would occur in the end of this vector instead of the beginning (if it would be flipped?) I tried if else statement with i==1 & i!=0, but this did not work as I wanted.